# Что использовать во vue, модели или переменные

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue3, vue-cli

До сих пор писал модели во vue:
 `data(){ return { some: "something" }}`
Но в последнее время и на официальном сайте и на vue school вижу что их прописывают через простые переменные, let, const. Я пропустил какое то нововведение или что?

Comment: https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/api/composition-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Vue обычно используется data для определения данных компонента. Это рекомендованный способ. Вот пример:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      some: 'something',
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

НО, во Vue.js 3 с использованием Composition API, вы можете использовать переменные вместо data. Например:

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const some = ref('something');

    return {
      some,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Короче говоря, это лишь один из вариантов, выбор между которыми остаётся за вами